# Select dots on image and modify the color of some of them

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I make a dotted map just like the one on the image below. I am using Illustrator and Photoshop.

How can I select and re-color some of the dots on this image?

[image: http://www.presentationmagazine.com/powerpoint-templates/00216/468slide1.jpg]

Comment: If you're working with that particular jpg, Illustrator is not the right tool. Use Photoshop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Photoshop, select one of the dots with the Magic Wand tool, then choose *Select > Similar*. This will select all the dots.

Use *Layer > New > Layer via Copy* to make a new layer from these dots, then in the Layers Panel, click the checkerboard icon next to the word Lock. This will prevent painting from leaking out of the dot area.

All you have to do now is to choose a colour, switch to the Brush tool and select a hard-edged brush, and paint the dots on the new layer. Only the dot area will be coloured.

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way and also ensures you won't ruin your original image.